# Changing a list of integers to a string for a file

Tags: python

I have a list of integers which i needed to be sorted and appear on screen (i got that down) but i also need it to be written into a new file.

```
 data = []
with open('integers.txt','r') as myfile:
   for line in myfile:
        data.extend(map(int, line.split(',')))
print (sorted (data))

text_file = open('sorted_integers.txt', 'w')
text_file.write(sorted(data))
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Why are you sorting the same data twice? Instead of calling the `sorted` function, you should sort the data in-place: `data.sort()`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point. Mind if I add that into my answer? (it slipped my mind that OP shouldn't be doing that)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Go for it! The `sorted` function can be handy, but it creates a new list, copies the data to it, and then calls the `.sort` method on that new list. So in a case like this it's more efficient to simply sort the original list.

Comment: Just use `text_file.write(str(data))`.

Comment: @martineau That's a bit messy, since it also writes the brackets.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write the sorted data to the new file without any newlines?

Comment: @PM2Ring: It changes the list of integers into a string which is what the OP asked how to do. It's as pretty as it would be if it appeared in a Python program.

Comment: I really have a very very basic understanding of coding.

Comment: @martineau Keep in mind that `str(data)` gives you very limited flexibility with delimiters when storing your data, even if you ignore the braces... with `print`, or anything else, you can change those things with minimal effort.

Comment: I'm try to make a programme that takes in a file, sorts it and puts it out in a new file, sorted. also wantiing it to display the sorted data. Cheers for all the help

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I know fairly well what's possible...but the OP wasn't talking about fancy formatting—in fact they never specified what format beyond `a string`.

Comment: Your code, and cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's code, writes the data to the new file all on a single line. If you don't want that, you need to tell us. And you need to decide how many numbers you want per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to save your output the same way your input was saved? In that case, you can painlessly use `print` with the `file` argument.

```
with open('sorted_integers.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(*sorted(data), sep=',', end='', file=f)
```

It is *always* recommended you use the `with...as` context manager when working with file I/O, it simplifies your code.

If you're working with python2.x, do a `__future__` import first:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

---

Another point (thanks, PM 2Ring) is that calling `list.sort` is actually more performant/efficient than `sorted`, since the original list is sorted *in place*, instead of returning a new list object, as `sorted` would do.

In summary,

```
data.sort() # do not assign the result!

with open('sorted_integers.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(*data, sep=',', end='', file=f)
```